# Проблема с запуском python в cmd

Tags: python, cmd

У меня стоит несколько версий python 3.7/3.8/3.9
Также стоит anaconda, я хочу запустить 3.8 через командную строку, но при вводе python
меня перекидывает в магазин (Не видит python), (ввод python38, python3, python3.8 не помогают)
в PATH добавлен, также добавлен лаунчер, остальные версии не добавлены. Стоят все питоны на C:, а Anaconda на D:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В папке с питоном версии 3.8 измените python.exe на python38.exe. Если путь к этому питону есть в PATH. То запуск в CMD так python38.exe

Comment: В магазин будет кидать по python или py

Comment: @Александр это не очень помогло, но я решил проблему просто переустановив python. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Можно и переустановить